# Is there a pattern of regular expression, that return all fullmatches of same chars?

Tags: python, regex

I want to use regular expressions to find the longest repeating letter combination or list of duplicate letters.

Here I have already found a pattern ('(?=(.))\1{2,}') for solving this problem. When I use search function it returns me first match. 
If I use findall, expecting to get a list of all matches, I get a list of symbols, where the length of each equals one.

```
import re
from Typing import List


def long_repeat(string: str) -> List[int]:
    pattern = re.compile(r'(?=(.))\1{2,}')
    counts = pattern.some_func(string)
    return counts
```

```
long_repeat('ddvvrwwwrggg') -> ['dd', 'vv', 'r', 'www', 'r','ggg']
long_repeat('iiaaggg') -> ['ii', 'aa', 'ggg']
long_repeat('abc') -> ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: you are getting long_repeat('ddvvrwwwrggg') -> ['dd', 'vv', 'r', 'www', 'r','ggg']. You want to output 'www' or 'ggg' from this?

Comment: After the function, I want to get a string that is alphabetically higher: 'ggg'!

Comment: sort the longest sequences in result. I guess you expect `aaaa` as result for `ddvvrwwwraaaaggg`

Comment: okay, i will add a for loop to find such a string after you have found your repeating list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
import re
from typing import List

_RGX = re.compile(r'(.)\1*')
def long_repeat(string: str) -> List[str]:
    return [m.group(0) for m in _RGX.finditer(string)]

print(long_repeat('ddvvrwwwrggg'))
# ['dd', 'vv', 'r', 'www', 'r', 'ggg']
print(long_repeat('iiaaggg'))
# ['ii', 'aa', 'ggg']
print(long_repeat('abc'))
# ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Or if you just want the longest one, with lexicographic priority:

```
import re

_RGX = re.compile(r'(.)\1*')
def longest_repeat(string: str) -> int:
    return min((m.group(0) for m in _RGX.finditer(string)), key=lambda s: (-len(s), s))

print(longest_repeat('ddvvrwwwrggg'))
# ggg
print(longest_repeat('iiaaggg'))
# ggg
print(longest_repeat('abc'))
# a
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add one for loop in your code

```
def find_max_length(array):
    max_len = -99
    max_string = ''
    for i in array:
        if(len(i) == max_len):
            if(i < max_string):
                max_string = i
                max_len = len(i)
        elif(len(i) > max_len):
            max_string = i
            max_len = len(i)
    return max_string
```

The output of above code

```
find_max_length(['dd', 'vv', 'r', 'www', 'r','ggg']) -> 'ggg'
```